# Unreliable spi read

Tags: arduino, embedded, raspberry-pi, spi

I am using raspberry pi and arduino for spi comm. Pi is the master and arduino is the slave.

On master, I am using the following python spi library  `https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev`

I have hardcoded for testing that when master sends two bytes, where the first byte is 0x1 then return 0x64 using :

```
if(0x1==command_type){
read_address=buf[1];
SPI.transfer(64); }
```

The problem is that read is returning mostly returning data I sent from master to slave.

[image]

Comment: Too little info to help you. Mention SPI frequency and setup (3-wire, 4-wire), double check all connections. Show your relevant RPi and Arduino setup code.

Comment: I figured this one out but stuck at some other point now.  If am writing to SPDR when I receive a command to send back 4 bytes. I send 4 bytes, where first byte is 0x4 (command to send back 3 bytes of data). It works fine till 500000 Hz but after that I simply receive the echo of the byte sent in the next cycle.